# align text center vertically in div column bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

simple question.
Have tried different ways to figure out, but all failed.
All I need is to align text vertically center in each columns in one row.
Here is the code:

```
<div class='row '>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'><p class="text-center ">dfgfg</p></div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'><p class="text-center">dfgfg</p></div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'><p class="text-center">dfgfg</p></div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'><p class="text-center">dfgfg</p></div>
            </div>
```

The text shows at the top of each column, I dont want to use margin-top for each 
text.
Any other way that I can align text vertically ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it using `line-height` as follows,and put this class in to every `<div>` s

```
.yo{
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rejBbY

Answer (score 0):

```css
.holider-height{
  display:table;
  height:500px;
}
.holider-height p{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

```html
<div class='row '>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6 holider-height'><p class="text-center ">dfgfg</p></div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6 holider-height'><p class="text-center">dfgfg</p></div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6 holider-height'><p class="text-center">dfgfg</p></div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6 holider-height'><p class="text-center">dfgfg</p></div>
            </div>
```